# Return list using git diff and grep

Tags: bash, git, grep, diff

I'm using git diff to return the file names of files recently changed and l’m trying to pipe the returned file names into a grep expression that searches each file and returns the files that have "*.yml" in the file name and "- name:" in the actual file. However it seems like my code only returns all the files in the directory that match the conditions, basically ignoring the git diff.

```
files=($(git -C ${dir} diff --name-only HEAD^ HEAD | grep -rlw --include="*.yml" --exclude-dir=$excluded -e "- name:"))
```

Any help would appreciated!

EDIT:
Solved! By removing the recursion and setting the git diff to a different variable, the correct list was returned.

```
git_diff_files=($(git -C ${prov_dir} diff --name-only HEAD^ HEAD))

changed_files_full=($(printf "${dir}/%s " "${git_diff_files[@]}" ))
changed_files_ansible=($(find "${changed_files_full[@]}" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -lw --include="*.yml" --exclude-dir="$excluded" -e "- name:"))
```

Comment: You are piping your file list to grep but in recursive mode grep ignores the standard input and searches recursively starting from the current directory... Try `files=($(git ...)); grep ... "${files[@]}"`.

Comment: `grep -rlw --include="*.yml" --exclude-dir=$excluded -e "- name:"`: This part is where things go wrong. Here, you're telling grep to recursively search for the pattern "- name:" in files that end with ".yml" and directories not in $excluded. However, this grep command isn't actually getting the output from the git command. It's just searching through all the files in the current directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this, using the best practices to feed an array, and avoid the form:

```
arr=( $(cmd) )
```

instead, use:

```
read -ra files < <(
    git -z -C "$dir" diff --name-only HEAD^ HEAD | grep -z '\.yml$'
)
printf '%s\n' "${files[@]}"
```

The `-z` from `git` & `grep` are meant to parse even files with newlines or special characters.